# Можно ли объединить следующие запросы или делать внутреннюю процедуру

Tags: sql, firebird

У меня в приложении есть несколько таблиц, и 5 DBComboBox, заполняющихся (каждый с нескольких таблиц) следующими запросами:

1-ый и 2-ой DBComboBox

```
select distinct * 
    from (
        select distinct(KEEP_ORGANIZATION) 
            from GOV_ETALON
            where KEEP_ORGANIZATION is not null 
        union all select distinct(STORED_ETALON) 
            from REGISTER_ETALON
            where STORED_ETALON is not null ) O, (
                select min(YEAR_ETALON) as MIN_YEAR, max(YEAR_ETALON) as MAX_YEAR
                    from GOV_ETALON
    ) Y
```

3-ий DBComboBox

```
select distinct *
    from (
        select distinct(KEEP_POSITION)
            from GOV_ETALON
            where KEEP_POSITION is not null
        union all select distinct(POSITION_PEOPLE)
            from USERS_DATA
            where POSITION_PEOPLE is not null
    ) P
```

4-ый DBComboBox

```
select distinct *
    from (
        select distinct(KEEP_DEGREE)
            from GOV_ETALON
            where KEEP_DEGREE is not null
        union all select distinct(DEGREE)
            from USERS_DATA
            where DEGREE is not null
    ) D
```

5-ый DBComboBox

```
select distinct *
    from (
        select distinct(KEEP_RANK)
            from GOV_ETALON
            where KEEP_RANK is not null
        union all select distinct(RANK)
            from USERS_DATA
            where RANK is not null 
    ) R
```

Я хотел узнать, можно ли их объединить в один запрос?
Или для повышения скорости делать внутреннюю процедуру, и загнать туда эти запросы, а ответом процедуры будут только соответствующие наборы?

Comment: Со схемой БД было бы проще ответить

Comment: Зачем distinct с union all? И потом вокруг этого ещё select? Разве просто select f from t1 union select f from t2 дают не верную выборку? union без all сам убирает повторяющиеся значения. Запросы теоретически хотя бы могут работать быстрее

Comment: **Serge Esmanovich**  Я заранее извиняюсь вы это имели в виду: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9mo0onvp7ehiay/shema.jpg?dl=0

Я просто еще не разобрался в этом "*DataBase Designer*" от *IBExprt*

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
create procedure vsezaprosi
as
begin
  // Zapros №1

  // Zapros №2

  // Zapros №3

  // Zapros №4

  // Zapros №5
end
```

полный текст

```
create procedure vsezaprosi
as
begin
    // Zapros №1 и №2
    select distinct * 
      from (
            select distinct(KEEP_ORGANIZATION) 
              from GOV_ETALON
             where KEEP_ORGANIZATION is not null 
             union all select distinct(STORED_ETALON) 
                         from REGISTER_ETALON
                        where STORED_ETALON is not null ) O, (
                       select min(YEAR_ETALON) as MIN_YEAR, max(YEAR_ETALON) as MAX_YEAR
                         from GOV_ETALON
        ) Y;

  // Zapros №3

    select distinct *
        from (
            select distinct(KEEP_POSITION)
                from GOV_ETALON
                where KEEP_POSITION is not null
            union all select distinct(POSITION_PEOPLE)
                from USERS_DATA
                where POSITION_PEOPLE is not null
        ) P;


  // Zapros №4

    select distinct *
        from (
            select distinct(KEEP_DEGREE)
                from GOV_ETALON
                where KEEP_DEGREE is not null
            union all select distinct(DEGREE)
                from USERS_DATA
                where DEGREE is not null
        ) D;

  // Zapros №5

    select distinct *
        from (
            select distinct(KEEP_RANK)
                from GOV_ETALON
                where KEEP_RANK is not null
            union all select distinct(RANK)
                from USERS_DATA
                where RANK is not null 
        ) R;

end
```